# 404 error in .htaccess

Tags: php

I am new to .htaccess and I want apply .htaccess rule to tags page. 
The actual page which I am using for tags is tagsearch. 
Here is my rule

```
RewriteRule tags/([a-z|A-Z|0-9]+)/$ tagsearch.php?tag=$1
```

Please advise.

Comment: so what error are you getting

Comment: Can you give example of what gives error and what expected behavior is?

Comment: I want to execute project on localhost and I have puttes all related files in www folder but it is giving me error: URL not found(404).I have tried to resolve this issue by changing location of related files but it is showing same error.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression character sets, `|` is **not** an "or" symbol, but the literal character `|`.

Are you maybe missing the initial slash `/` in the target URL, and want to make the trailing slash optional?

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/tags/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /tagsearch.php?tag=$1
```

Try to **enable logging**. There is a "RewriteLog" statement for debugging rewrite issues.